# Как вытащить все комментарии из текстового файла на Linux?

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, grep

Перебрал великое множество разных утилит на Linux, в итоге так ни к чему и не пришёл. Они все валятся на многострочных комментариях. Остановился на grep с ключом -E. Корректен ли такой способ получения всех комментариев в си-стиле из файла?

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, подходящую утилиту и если надо,то регулярку.

Comment: Может, `grep -Eoz "/\*+[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/"`?

Comment: Во-первых, чем обусловлен такой странный набор тегов `javascript`, `linux`, `grep`? Во-вторых, ваша задача очень не обычная (вытаскивать из си-кода комменатрии и именно в bash'е). Хотелось бы знать почему именно bash'ем и что вы дальше собираетесь делать с этими комментариями? Будете с ними и дальше работать в bash'е?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Да, это работает! Вы чёртов волшебник! Пожалуйста, оставьте это в виде ответа, чтобы я мог его принять.

Comment: Наличие тегов linux/grep/regexp объяснять не вижу смысла, а javascript наличествует здесь, поскольку 80% перерытых мной ответов до этого тематически относились именно к JS. Людям, работающим с JS, я предположил, эта тематика ближе. Моя ведь задача - при помощи тегов, очертить для себя целевую аудиторию.

Comment: В общем, тег JavaScript надо убрать. Удалил.

Comment: поставил причину закрытия: «вопрос слишком общий», так как не озвучены критерии того, что именно следует считать комментариями. ведь существует **огромное количество** форматов файлов, в которых описаны всевозможные правила комментирования.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Нет, вы не правы. В вопросе явно указано "комментариев в си-стиле".

Comment: @Bulbum, согласен, упоминается. но это **критически** важная информация, которую следует указать непосредственно в заголовке.

Comment: *sed* это штатно делает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться

```
grep -Eoz "/\*+[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/"
```

**Опции**

- `E` - задает синтаксис регулярок POSIX ERE (использует более соврменный и понятный большинству синтаксис регулярок, где `+` это квантификатор, а не знак `+`)
- `o` - задает режим выдачи найденных совпадений, а не целых строк
- `z` - делает возможным поиск совпадений между несколькими строками.

**Регулярное выражение**

- `/` - знак `/`
- `\*+` - 1 и более знаков `*`
- `[^*]*` - 0 и более знаков, отличных от `*`
- `\*+` - 1 и более знаков `*`
- `([^/*][^*]*\*+)*` - 0 и более повторов

  - `[^/*]` - символ, отличный от `/` и `*`
  - `[^*]*` - 0 и более знаков, отличных от `*`
  - `\*+` - 1 и более знаков `*`
- `/` - знак `/`

Comment: Сложно. *sed* штатно умеет.

Comment: @0andriy Удалять такие комментарии `sed` умеет хорошо, `sed -r ':a; s%(.*)/\*.*\*/%\1%; ta; /\/\*/ !b; N; ba' file`. С поиском совпадений у него не очень. `sed -n '/\/\*/,/\*\//p' file` не даёт правильного результата.

Comment: `sed -n -e '/PATTERN_FROM/,/PATTERN_TO/p'`, где `PATTERN_FROM` соответственно первой строки, и `PATTERN_TO` — псоледней в блоке, который нужно куда-то деть. Учимся читать документацию, да?

Comment: Это не работает, я проверял

Comment: Работает, я тоже проверял перед тем, как писать сюда.